# Formula to sum items in a column only if other column has specific value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel table with 2 columns. First column contains a string such as A,B,C and second column contains numbers. I want to obtain sum of numbers in each row if text of first column for that row is equal to given text.

For example:

A 2
C 3
B 4
A 1
C 3

formula(A) = 3
formula(B) = 4
formula(C) = 6
and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this is via SubTotal option. Follow the example in this link [Creating subtotals](http://www.gcflearnfree.org/excel2013/20.2)

Another way to do the same is using sumif function follow this link [Sumif function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b)

Comment: The first link here is broken. This answer should contain the actual example of how to do it, and not only link to other sites.

Answer (score -1):

SUMIFS() is capable of doing this. As is SUMPRODUCT()

In european excel this would look like this. I don't know where your reference is so I am putting it in a cell named Reference.

```
SUMIFS($B:$B;$A:$A;"="Reference)
```

If you want a "running" count, then replace the arrays - from $B:$B to B$2:B2 and similar with $A:$A, and copy it down the rows.